# Fragments in ViewPager2 does not respond to clicks if scroll position is 0

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-touch-event, android-viewpager2

I am very glad that Google released [ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2) which is built on RecyclerView to solve a lot of issues that the old ViewPager has.

I quickly replaced my old ViewPager codes to ViewPager2:

1. Replace ViewPager with ViewPager2 in xml
2. Replace `FragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager)` with `FragmentStateAdapter(Fragment)`
3. ViewPager setup is as below:

   ```
   viewPager.adapter = fragmentAdapter

   val mediator = TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager, true) { tab, position ->
       tab.text = fragmentAdapter.tabNames[position]
   }
   mediator.attach()
   ```

No other changes have been made.

#### The problem

After performing the above change, I realized a problem -

Now my ViewPager is an ordinary horizontal pager, and each fragment in my `fragmentAdapter` has a vertical `RecyclerView`.

**I observed that when ever the scroll position of the RecyclerView is 0, my items in that RecyclerView cannot receive any click nor long click events, but it can be scrolled. Once it is scrolled, it can receive clicks again.***

Knowing that `ViewPager2` is a `RecyclerView` as well, is there something to do with nested RecyclerView?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out it's probably a bug in either `ConstraintLayout` or `ViewPager2`.

The container of `ViewPager2` was originally a `ConstraintLayout`, and after I changed it to `LinearLayout`, it simply worked.

I tried to reproduce the issue in a sample project but I can't reproduce even if I used `ConstraintLayout`... So there must be some other conditions to make that happen.

Comment: Yes, I changed ConstraintLayout to FrameLayout and it started working. Definitely some bug with ConstraintLayout

Comment: Thanks. I had been stuck at this for hours.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I was also stuck on this for hours _/\_

Comment: I was facing the same issue, and i changed the container to linear layout and it worked.

Comment: Changing to Linearlayout didn't work for me and I still have that issue.